# What is the usage of the second "with"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> *The premier enjoyed the limelight early in his tenure for an economic reform stance heavy on empowering the private sector. He is credited **with** improving the job market and promoting the growth of China's internet economy, **with** Tencent Holdings and Alibaba Group Holding rising to become two of the world's most valuable companies.*
>
> [Nikkei Asian Review](https://asia.nikkei.com/Politics-Economy/Policy-Politics/Chinese-premier-fades-to-secondary-role-despite-re-election): *Chinese premier fades to secondary role despite re-election*

*internet economy, **with** Tencent Holdings*

Why is the preposition "with" used a second time? What is the "with" meant for?

Comment: for inclusion ?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What on earth are you talking about? The meaning is quite clear, even if it's a little awkward on first blush.

Comment: The second "with" introduces a prepositional phrase, which extends to the end of the quoted sentence, and which modifies "growth". The object of this second "with" is the gerund "rising".

Comment: Who modified the question that already answered my question.

Comment: Who modified the question that answered my question? Are you referring to me who edited and improved the formatting? I included the source and emphasized the preposition in **bold** for clarity. Or were you referring to an answer? No answer has ever been posted. Or were you referring to a comment that was posted? The author of the comment probably self-deleted it because they made a mistake or misunderstood something.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Yes. You added bold on the first "with", that answered my question. Perviously, I had thought, "internet economy, with Tencent Holdings". After your bold, I got the point, " He is credited with improving ... , with Tencent Holdings ... "

Comment: You can remove the bold if you dislike the edit.

Comment: I showed that "with" was used twice, I did not answer your question. I added the context, the source, and included the identity of "he". If the edit helped you understand, then maybe you should thank me? :)

Comment: "You can remove the bold if you dislike the edit."
No, I like it.
"..thank me"
Yes, thank you.:)
The post all lost my format with line feeds.